# Issue with Bluetooth connection. Raspberry pi3 and nodejs 7.4.0

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Ass everyone saying in their first posts "I'm new one" and trying to figure out one complexity.

1. I want to scan and create list of available wifi networks in Raspberry area and send the list to the phone via bluetooth.
2. Next - select one of the networks in the list on the phone, enter a password to selected network and send back via bluetooth to Raspberry

I'm using Raspberry pi3 with bluetooth on board, Raspbian OS and nodejs v7.4.0

I choose [wifi-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifi-control) to work with wifi network and it works greate. One thing - I should run **npm run** with **sudo** to get all networks, not just current one;

Then I'm trying to work with bluetooth via [bluetooth-serial-port](https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port) lib.
First of all I did all preparations that was written in documentation.

```js
var btSerial = new (require('bluetooth-serial-port')).BluetoothSerialPort();

btSerial.inquire();
```

And it does nothing. At least I don't see any effect - my phone doesn't "see" Raspberry in available bluetooth devices list;

I thought that my Raspberry has porblems with bluetooth, but then I run

**bluetoothctl -> power on -> discoverable on**

And Raspberry appeared on phone.

**What should I do to "turn on" Bluetooth control and add my Raspberry to list of available bluetooth devices?**

Peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the exact same problem. My solution (which might or might not be fitting for your needs) was to pair the phone via `bluetoothctl` beforehand. (this already is you why this solution kinda sucks: you can't come and use a different phone/pi the next day, stuff got completely screwed when changing to a different pi :D)
Oh and the main script should run as root, else all of this wont work.

**1) Pairing your device**

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetoothctl] agent on
[bluetoothctl] discoverable on
[bluetoothctl] pairable on
[bluetoothctl] scan on
```

(now you turn on your bluetooth on your phone and search for devices, in bluetoothctl you should see your device and mac to be shown)

```
[bluetoothctl] pair XX:XX...(MAC of your phone)
```

(phone is going to show the "yo this device wants to pair"-dialog and bluetoothctl wants you to confirm the pairing too)

Now you can always connect to the pi via bluetooth, if it is discoverable or not. (I'm using [Serial Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal))

**2) Actual talking between devices**

*NONE* of the npm packages supposed to work with bluetooth worked for me. Not a single one. So in the end I used `rfcomm` and it's ability to start a program on connection. Together with [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) I let `rfcomm` run `node myscript.js`, which establishes the actual serial connection like so:

**2.1) `rfcomm` waiting for connections**

```
const rfcommProc = spawn(
    'rfcomm',
    ['watch', 'hci0', '1', 'node', `${__dirname}/myscript.js`]
);
```

**2.2) `myscript.js` opening the port**

```
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/rfcomm0', spError => {
    if (spError) {
        process.send(spError);
    }
})
```

Look up on the npmjs-page how to receive and send stuff now.(:
Hope this gives you some ideas and/or helped.

**3) Note**

- The bluetooth service starts quite late. Making a service requiring it didn't do the job for me, but adding it to `rc.local` seems to be "late enough" to have it running and listening on startup.